# How to destroy/delete a QML component dynamically?

Tags: qt, qml

I'm trying to dynamically create and then destroy a component based on user interaction with a checkbox in QML. Check box on, create component. Check box off, destroy component. Creating the component works, but destroying it doesn't. The component is still there.

The documentation in QT docs [here](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qdeclarativedynamicobjects.html) mention that the destroy method should work after creating a component. Any ideas what I could be doing wrong here? Code given below.

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1

Rectangle {
    property var deficiencyType
    width: 600
    height: 800
    color:"white"
    CheckBox {
        id:checkbox
        text: "Check deficiency on/off"
        onClicked: {
            if (checked) {
                deficiencyType = Qt.createComponent("Form.qml")
                deficiencyType.createObject(columnRef)
            } else {
                deficiencyType.destroy()
                console.log(deficiencyType)
            }
        }
    }
    ColumnLayout {
        id:columnRef
        Layout.fillHeight: true
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        anchors {
            top: checkbox.bottom
            topMargin: 10
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Alaenix said, a Loader may work for you instead. But to directly answer your question, the problem with your destroy() is that you're destroying the component, not the object that you created. So changing this code:

```
                    deficiencyType = Qt.createComponent("Form.qml")
                    deficiencyType.createObject(columnRef)
```

to this:

```
                    var component = Qt.createComponent("Form.qml")
                    deficiencyType = component.createObject(columnRef)
```

should resolve your problem.

Comment: Although using Loaders might be best practice like @Alaenix said, this answer solves the problem I had. I didn't mention that I had to generate multiple forms, so Loaders would take more time to configure for that. But this works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 2):

For this usecase, you could use a [Loader](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html), like this :

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1

Rectangle {
    width: 600
    height: 800
    color:"white"

    CheckBox {
        id: checkBox

        text: "Check deficiency on/off"
    }

    ColumnLayout {
        Layout.fillHeight: true
        Layout.fillWidth: true

        anchors {
            top: checkbox.bottom
            topMargin: 10
        }

        Loader {
            id: formLoader

            active: checkBox.checked
            source: "Form.qml"
        }
    }
}
```

There is several way to handle dynamic QML components. You should also check those ones :

- [Instantiator](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-instantiator.html)
- [Repeater](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-repeater.html)

EDIT:

To handle several items dynamic creation from a specific model, you should use a Repeater like this :

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Layouts 2.14
import QtQuick.Controls 2.14

Rectangle {
    width: 600
    height: 900
    color:"white"

    property ListModel forms: ListModel {
        ListElement {
            formName: "Form one"
            formSource: "Form1.qml"
        }

        ListElement {
            formName: "Form two"
            formSource: "Form2.qml"
        }

        ListElement {
            formName: "Form three"
            formSource: "Form3.qml"
        }
    }

    RowLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent

        Repeater {
            model: forms

            delegate: Item {
                CheckBox {
                    id: checkBox

                    text: "Check " + modelData.formName + " on/off"
                }

                ColumnLayout {
                    Layout.fillHeight: true
                    Layout.fillWidth: true

                    anchors {
                        top: checkbox.bottom
                        topMargin: 10
                    }

                    Loader {
                        active: checkBox.checked
                        source: modelData.formSource
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree that most of the time Qt.createComponent/createObject is not needed. Less imperative code is better. To be even more declarative you could simply bind the Loader's `active` property to the CheckBox's `checked` property and get rid of the `onClicked` signal handler.

Comment: Thank you for the Loader example. This would definitely work for the example I have above. But I didn't mention that I have 10 different checkboxes that all generate 10 different forms, possibly at the same time. So I need to set multiple sources for Loader source. This is why I didn't pursue Loader at first. I can create 10 different loaders, but is that best practice here?

Comment: You should use a Repeater to dynamically creates multiple different QML Item. Look at the [`model`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-repeater.html#model-prop) property that enables you to provide a data list model.